# Dll .NET Framwerok 3.5 con referencias a DLL 4.5 (No Compilar) C#

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy realizando una bibliotecas de clases (DLL) para crear un `automation` para Dynamics NAV 2009.

Mi idea es crear un `DLL` que contenga otra embebida Dentro (Ya lo he hecho otras veces) usando :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222655/embedding-assemblies-inside-another-assembly

El problema es que para que el automation sea válido para Dynamics NAV 2009 debe ser como máximo compilada en .NET Framework 3.5 pero la `DLL` embebida que tengo dentro del proyecto como referencia es 4.5

A la hora de compilar me dice lo siguiente :

> Gravedad  Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado de supresión
>   Advertencia       La referencia principal "Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.MX" no se
>   pudo resolver porque se generó con la versión de .NET Framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5". Esta es una versión posterior a la
>   versión de .NET Framework de destino actual
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5". Dynasoft.Dynamics.Nav.MX

Hay alguna posibilidad de usar una referencia creada en framework 4.5 para un proyecto en 3.5 ?

Saludos y gracias

Comment: por el mensaje de error parece ser una validacion que aplica el mismo Dynamics NAV, por lo que aunque desde .net 3.5 puedes invocar funcionalidad compilada con .net 4.5 crees que seria de utilidad? mas que nada porque es la propia aplicacion quien limita esto

Comment: Hay alguna forma de evitar eso y hacer que esto compile?? , no te preocupes el Ordenador Destino tiene framework 4.5 , sólo que para que la dll sea visible en Dynamics tiene que ser como máximo 3.5 , lo que estoy haciendo es una dll intermedia (Wrapper) :( , o esa es la idea

Comment: no puedes cambiar la version del framework que usas en el proyecto de la librerias dll, pasandola a .net 3.5 y compilar nuevamente?  esto lo cambias desde las propiedades del proyecto class library. No hay un equivalente de la libreria embebida que sea compatible con .net 3.5?

Comment: no evaluaste en lugar de embeber la dll dentro de otro, simplemente registrarla en el GAC, de esta forma si tienes .net 4.5 en el servidor instalador podrias invocar la funcionalidad sin que Dynamic Nav lo valide

Comment: Hola, ¿llegaste a probar alguna de las opciones que te hemos comentado? ¿las ves factibles?  En el tiempo que llego en esto he tenido muchas peleas con `Interop` (aunque no con Navision) y me intriga si algo de esto funciona

Answer (score 2):

Lo que recomendaría es que las `dll` en lugar de embeberlas una dentro de otras las registres en la `GAC`
Analizando la documentación

[Extending Microsoft Dynamics NAV Using Microsoft .NET Framework Interoperability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg502499.aspx)

Se menciona el uso de la GAC como medio para publicar componentes .net y consumirlos desde Dynamic NAV. 
Si tienes ambos frameworks instalados en el server las librerias podrian interactuar entre ellas.

Answer (score 1):

Estoy de acuerdo con Leandro Tuttini, quizás si registras los ensamblados en el `GAC` se solucione el problema.

Por aportar algo más, el problema también podría estar en las referencias a los ensamblados de interoperabilidad de `Navision` y que, con "La referencia principal", se refiera a [`Ensamblados de Interoperabilidad Primarios (PIA)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302338.aspx)

Lo que podría estar ocurriendo es que las referencias a los ensamblados de `Interop` de `Navision` no sean las correctas. Algo que podría solucionarlo es agregar las referencias a través de los archivos de ensamblado y no desde COM (no se si será el caso).

Otra cosa que suele dar problemas al trabajar con referencias `Interop` es la opción [Incrustar tipos de interoperabilidad](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd409610.aspx) que en la mayor parte de los casos hay que deshabilitar

Answer (score 1):

Si no es posible utilizar 3.5 en tu librería auxiliar, con la 4.5 deberás [firmarla](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-sign-an-assembly-with-a-strong-name) y [registrarla](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-install-an-assembly-into-the-gac) en el GAC.

Es posible que tengas que modificar la llamada entre las librerías, en vez de referenciarlas o utilizar [llamadas de manera dinámica en tu código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/145813/problemas-con-entrypoint-de-dll-creada-en-c/148444#148444).

Microsoft no recomienda gacutil para entornos de producción **aunque funciona**, aconseja crear un instalador para su distribución.

En la [máquina de destino](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd301269.aspx) debes tener instalados ambos framework, si el sistema operativo es [Windows Server 2003](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/138985/registrar-dll-en-gac-en-windows-server-2003-sobre-framework-4-0) no podrás hacerlo...