# Registrar DLL en GAC en Windows Server 2003 sobre framework 4.0

Tags: .net, windows-server

Sobre un servidor Windows Server 2003 Standard x86 SP2 intento registrar una DLL generada con framework de destino 4.0 x86

La DLL [no tiene ninguna referencia ni dependencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138735/error-this-assembly-is-built-by-a-runtime-newer-than-the-currently-loaded-runti) de versiones posteriores, comprobado tanto en el proyecto como con un decompilado posterior.

Utilizando gacutil.exe del [SDK Framework 4.0](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8289751b-be25-4a23-a5e2-709645b8c651/net-4-gacutil-on-production-server?forum=netfxsetup) apaprece el error:

```
Error al agregar el ensamblado a la caché: Este ensamblado se creó con un tiempo de ejecución más reciente que el tiempo de ejecución cargado actualmente y no se puede cargar.
```

Lo que da a entender que la versión instalada final no coincide, pero si es posible registrar la DLL con "regasm.exe" pero no con "...\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe" además en el momento de ejecutar gacutil la versión de esta herramienta no es la misma

**¿Existe gacutil 4.0 para x86 en Windows Server 2003?**
¿Se puede registrar una DLL 4.0 en el GAC de un Server 2003 SP2?

```
Utilidad de registro de ensamblados de Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1998-2004.  Reservados todos los derechos.
Se registraron correctamente los tipos
La exportación del ensamblado a 'C:\TEST\MIDLL.tlb'
y el registro de la biblioteca de tipos se realizaron correctamente

Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 3.5.30729.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. Reservados todos los derechos.

Error al agregar el ensamblado a la caché: Este ensamblado se creó con un
tiempo de ejecución más reciente que el tiempo de ejecución cargado 
actualmente y no se puede cargar.
```

*Actualizado 1*: con la versión de SDK NETFX 4.5.1 Tools la versión de gacutil sería la necesitaria

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools>gacutil
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.33440
```

En un equipo con Windows 10, pero para Windows Server 2003 x86 SP2 sucede lo mismo que con las posteriores (entiendo que con XP sería lo mismo)

```
gacutil.exe no es una aplicación Win32 válida
```

*Actualizado 2*: No es posible utilizar la versión de [powershell](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Gac/1.0.1) con los comandos para instalación en GAC, al tratarse de una versión antigua para 2003:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
$publisher = New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish
$publisher.GacInstall("C:\Components\MyComponent.dll")
```

Referencias adicionales:

- [Versiones y dependencias Windows - Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies)
- [Actualización 4.0.3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/2600211/update-4-0-3-for-microsoft-net-framework-4-runtime-update)
- [Requisitos Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/8z6watww(v=vs.100).aspx): 2003 y 2003 R2 incluidos
- [Subversiones 4.0.XXX](https://www.aidinit.com/2012/10/clr-dll-revision-history-for-microsoft-net-framework-4/)
- [Dependencias y directorio de SDK 4.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mjeelani/2010/06/07/top-2-things-you-should-know-about-the-global-assembly-cache-gac-in-net-4-0/)

Comment: Prueba a ejecutar esto en un powershell a ver que versiones de gacutil tienes: `(Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)' -Filter gacutil.exe -Recurse) | Select-Object { $_.FullName }`

Comment: gacutil.exe esta en otra carpeta separada, he probado con 3 diferentes: $_.FullName
-------------
C:\MICARPETA\_UTIL\gacutil.exe
C:\MICARPETA\_UTIL\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe
C:\MICARPETA\_UTIL\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe
C:\MICARPETA\_UTIL\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\gacutil.exe
C:\MICARPETA\_UTIL\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe
C:\MICARPETA\_UTIL\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil.exe
C:\MICARPETA\_UTIL\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe

Comment: Y estas seguro de que el servidor tiene instalado el .net framework adecuado?

Comment: Si, esta instalado 4.0 reparado, reiniciado, actualizado con la 4.0.3 como indicaba, aparece en panel de control Extended y Client Profile, por lo que esta instalado con el paquete Full. La herramienta  gacutil incorporada en el SDK 4.0 parece ser versión 3.5 y las posteriores no son válidas en la máquina.

Comment: Hmm..pero los gacutil que has intentado los has copiado tu al servidor? no estaba instalado ya en una ruta similar a `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe`?

Comment: Por otro lado, veo que las versiones que me pones son todas x64. Has probado con las de 32 bits?

Comment: en el servidor no estan instalados, pero la misma metolodía funciona en otros servidores con versiones diferentes. Como indicaba es todo para x86 las de x64 se copian en un subdirectorio pero no se utilizan.

Comment: Como puede ser que instalando el framework 4.0 no se instale el CLR 4? (utilizando la aplicación clrver.exe)

Comment: Es muy extraño, debería estar instalado al instalar el framework la verdad. Echa un vistazo a [esto](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1042155/How-to-Install-gacutil-exe-on-a-Windows-Server) a ver si te vale

Comment: Los métodos alternativos para instalar en GAC tampoco funcionarán si no está el CLR correcto... el SDK no debe instalarse en producción, ralmente gacutil tampoco debería utilizarse en producción (recomendación de MS) pero...

Comment: Volveríamos a la misma pregunta planteada: ¿Se puede registrar una DLL 4.0 en el GAC de un Server 2003 SP2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente si es posible instalar pero es necesario crear un proyecto SETUP que incluya los componentes en el GAC.

El proceso finaliza correctamente, es posible ver las dll en las carpetas de ensamblado como 4.0 pero al instanciarlas vuelve a aparecer el mismo error.

No hay soporte por parte de Microsoft, ni lo habrá teniendo en cuenta la casuística y las versiones antiguas. Por tanto la recomendación y solución pasa poder dejar, por fin, de utilizar máquinas con un sistema operativo de hace más de 15 años (normal por otra parte).