# Problemas con EntryPoint de DLL creada en C

Tags: c#, c

Necesito usar una DLL creada en C en una aplicación C#.

He seguido varias formas vistas en internet y no logro utilizar los métodos que se supone están en la DLL.

Al buscar los entrypoint me aparecen 4, que son los siguientes.

```
DllCanUnloadNow
DllGetClassObject
DllRegisterServer
DllUnregisterServer
```

¿Alguien sabe como poder  utilizar la DLL correctamente? Creo que está hecha como COM.

Lo he intentado así.

```
[DllImport("DLL.dll", EntryPoint = "DllCanUnloadNow")]
    public static extern int IniciarDia();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Console.WriteLine(IniciarDia());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Gracias de antemano.

EDIT: Lo pude solucionar, pude acceder a los métodos de la DLL.
Tuve que registrar la dll en windows y pude agregarla como referencia en el proyecto.
De esa forma pude usar el using archivo.lib.

Me apoyé en esta página
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973800.aspx

Saludos.

Comment: Deberías colocar las formas en que lo has intentado.

Comment: Modificada la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te da?

Comment: No me reconoce los métodos, por ejemplo si pongo ese de IniciarDia() o uno que se llame Hola(), da el mismo resultado (un 0). Si le saco el entrypoint="", dice que no lo encuentra.

Comment: O sea, que no te da ningun error? El problema es que te devuelve un 0?

Comment: Si le quito el EntryPoint = "DllCanUnloadNow", me da el error System.EntryPointNotFoundException. Si lo uso, use el método que sea, incluso si no está en la dll, me devuelve un 0.

Comment: Parece un poco extraño, pero si no te da error es que si está encontrando el entry point. De todas maneras, sin ver el código de la dll es complicado ver cual es el problema...

Comment: Solo tengo los métodos de la dll, la hizo un proveedor externo. No tengo acceso a el código en sí.
¿Será error del entrypoint?. Según he leído debería tener métodos expuestos para usar y esos de DllCanUnloadNow no creo que sean los correctos.
No se que tan perdido estoy con el tema, primera vez que trabajo con dll's.

Comment: Efectivamente, si esos son los entry points, es una dll de COM. ¿No deberías accederla usando los servicios de COM entonces? Pero si aún quieres usar el entry point, sugiero el de DllRegisterServer, y que use el de DllUnRegisterServer al final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo pude solucionar, pude acceder a los métodos de la DLL. Tuve que registrar la dll en windows y pude agregarla como referencia en el proyecto. De esa forma pude usar el using archivo.lib.

Me apoyé en esta página https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973800.aspx

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar una llamada a una clase/método de una librería registrada mediante objectos *dynamic* a partir del framework 4.0 de manera simplificada contra un COM:

```
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Componente.Libreria");
dynamyc obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

En este caso para un componente COM firmado, expuesto y registrado (*espacio de nombres* en .NET)

- [C# 3.0 vs 4.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2009/05/01/a-simple-sample-for-c-4-0-dynamic-feature/)
- [Interoperabilidad](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic#com-interop)